# $\lim_{n\to\infty}E[XI_{A_n}]=0.$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

My school has ended and this caught my attention when I was reviewing.

> Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$. Let $X \in L^1$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ and let $\left\{A_n\in\mathcal{A}:n\geq1\right\}$ be a sequence of sets such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)=0$. Show that
> $\lim_{n\to\infty}E[XI_{A_n}]=0.$ (Not assuming that $\lim_{n\to\infty}XI_{A_n}=0$ a.s.).

My approach at that time is to use the linearity of $E$ and indicator method. Where goes
$$\begin{gather}
\lim_{n\to\infty}E[XI_{A_n}] = E[X]P[\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n]\to 0
\end{gather}$$
Which I thought is quite neat. However, the answer provided by our TA was.

> [image]

Is my approach not rigorous, and may anyone explain a bit on the TA's solution? Thanks.

**Thanks again sincerely for all the replies, they are all really instructive!**

Comment: Say what theorem you are using in the first equality. You cannot base proofs on just intuition.

Comment: Like said, linearity of E makes E[XI] -> E[X]E[I] and indicator method E[I] -> P(A) @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: That's not linearity unless $I = 0$ identically or $I=1$ identically.  You have the product of two random variables, so unless they're uncorrelated (not guaranteed), you cannot write $E[XI] = E[X]E[I]$.

Comment: I see, yes I neglected that. Thank you very much! @BrianMoehring

Comment: Your TA's solution needs correction too, though... their first equality needs justified (it's possible this is what Kavi was referencing rather than your argument) and a lot of the work with $M$ isn't correct (it looks like they tried to simplify a known proof and made some errors)

Comment: This is because the measure $\nu(A) = \int_A |X| dP$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $P$, that is, $\nu \ll P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TA's solution needs correction.  I would write it like this [with as few changes as possible]:

> $|XI_{\{|X|>n\}}| \leq |X|, X \in L^1$
>
> By the Dominated Convergence Theorem, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}E\left[|XI_{\{|X|>n\}}|\right] = E\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}|XI_{\{|X|>n\}}|\right] = E[0]=0$$
> Note that, $\forall M > 0$, $$\begin{align*}0 \leq \left|E[XI_{A_n}]\right| \leq E\left[|X|I_{A_n}\right] &= E\left[|X|I_{A_n}I_{\{|X|>M\}}\right] + E\left[|X|I_{A_n}I_{\{|X|\leq M\}}\right] \\ &\leq E\left[|X|I_{\{|X|>M\}}\right] + MP(A_n)\end{align*}$$
> $$\implies 0 \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} |E[XI_{A_n}]| \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(E\left[|X|I_{\{|X|>M\}}\right] + MP(A_n)\right) = E\left[|X|I_{\{|X|>M\}}\right]$$
> $$\implies 0 \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} |E[XI_{A_n}]| = \lim_{M\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty} |E[XI_{A_n}]| \leq \lim_{M\to\infty} E\left[|X|I_{\{|X|>M\}}\right] = 0$$
> Thus, $\lim_{n\to\infty} E[XI_{A_n}] = 0$

Comment: As a note, you don't actually need the full strength of the dominated convergence theorem there, as the downward version of the monotone convergence theorem also applies directly, if you have it.

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to the following elementary measure-theory result: if $f \in L^1(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$, then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $E \in \mathcal{M}$, $\mu(E)<\delta$ implies $\int_{E} |f| < \epsilon$.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096049/proving-epsilon-delta-convergence-of-lebesgue-integrals-just-from-the-defi) for a proof.

Answer (score 2):

Integrable random variable $X$ has a property that for any $\varepsilon>0$,
there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\int_{B}|X|dP<\varepsilon$ whenever
$B\in\mathcal{A}$ and $P(B)<\delta$.

Your assertion follows from this fact immediately.

To prove this fact: Firstly, note that this is true if $X$ is bounded.
For if $|X|\leq M$ for some $M>0$, then given $\varepsilon>0$ we
simply take $\delta=\frac{1}{2M}\varepsilon$.

For the general case, let $Y_{n}=\min(|X|,n)$. By Monotone Convergence
Theorem Theorem, $\int Y_{n}dP\rightarrow\int|X|dP$. In particular,
given $\varepsilon>0$, we choose $n$ such that $0\leq\int\left(|X|-Y_{n}\right)dP<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$
Since $Y_{n}$ is bounded, we can further choose $\delta>0$ such
that $\int_{B}Y_{n}dP<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ whenever $P(B)<\delta$.
Now, let $B\in\mathcal{A}$ with $P(B)<\delta$. We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{B}|X|dP\\
 & = & \int_{B}\left(|X|-Y_{n}\right)dP+\int_{B}Y_{n}dP\\
 & \leq & \int\left(|X|-Y_{n}\right)dP+\int_{B}Y_{n}dP\\
 & < & \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\\
 & = & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: +1, slick proof of this result for the finite measure case. Just a note, I suppose you're using that $X \in L^1$ when you make the leap from $\int Y_n dP \to \int |X| dP$ to $0 \leq \int |X| - Y_n dP < \epsilon/2$, since the $\epsilon-N$ definition of a convergent sequence only works if the convergent value is finite (if it was infinite, the definition is of course slightly different).